# call_user_func ... valid callback

Tags: php, wordpress, callback, comments

I have practically 0 PHP knowledge.  I have a wp blog, I just published my first post, and when I try to use the comments, I get the following:

`Warning: call_user_func(twentyten_comment) [function.call-user-func]: First argument is expected to be a valid callback in /home/erisdesi/public_html/wp-includes/comment-template.php on line 1308`

Here's the post: http://www.erisdesigns.net/2010/08/27/make-your-own-20xx-daily-planner/

I wish I could be more helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error means it's trying to call a function named `twentyten_comment` but that function is not defined (or if it is defined, it's not in the scope of the script).

The cause might be the theme or a plugin. Maybe try disabling plugins one-by-one to see if it fixes it?

Comment: That makes sense.  I'm actually not using that theme, but it's installed.  Would a solution be to overwrite the file calling the funtion manually with my theme's file?

Comment: If you don't plan to use the theme, you might be better off removing it altogether (or maybe re-installing it).

Comment: Yes, I think I see the problem here.  btw @Ash White, just deactivated all plug-ins one by one and nothing changed.

Comment: So I've uninstalled it, and still no dice.  Can you tell me which file is calling this funtion?  I checked comment-template.php, and there's no mention in the code of twentyten.

Comment: So `comment_template.php` doesn't reference `twentyten_comment` on like 1308? Is it possible that the post is cached (via a plugin or some other method)?

Comment: No it does not.  And yeah, cached perhaps by a plug-in called Post Page Associator, which helps me by associating all posts and categories with certain pages.  I uninstalled it, and it didn't change anything.

Comment: I solved it!  Seems the comments.php file was left over from the old theme, and for some reason didn't get overwritten when I installed the new one.  Thanks for your help @Ash White, I'll give you the check.

Answer (score 2):

This might be due to one of the reasons:

1. The callback method is not defined.
2. Issue with the scope of callback method.

2nd issue can be resolved by trying to call the callback method using `$this` if your callback method is present in the same class where you are binding the hook with callback fuction **like**:

```
class my_sample_plugin_page 
 {
function __construct(){
    add_action('admin_menu',array( $this, 'admin_menu_call' ));
}
function admin_menu_call () {
    add_options_page( 'Page Title','Circle Tree Login','manage_options','options_page_slug', array( $this, 'settings_page' ) );
}
function  settings_page () {
    echo 'This is the page content';
}
}
new my_sample_plugin_page;
```

Thus in above code callback method `admin_menu_call` is called using `$this`.

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue in comments.php within your theme. Search for this:

```
wp_list_comments( array( 'callback' => 'twentyten_comment' ) );
```

Remove the parameters, so it should look like this:

```
wp_list_comments();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after hours of investigating, I just changed the theme and it worked! I know it's not ideal solution, but it is a quick fix, just what I needed, because I'm currently working on a wp plugin. cheers!